# I have a command on mouse button number 1, I want it to work as well on button number 7 and number 8? On my Logitech mouse

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have a script that works on mouse button number 1, I want the same script that also works on mouse button 7 and 8 Is this possible?

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            Sleep(200)
            repeat
                MoveMouseRelative(0,6)
                Sleep(30)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end                
    end
end
```

Comment: What behavior do you want for buttons 7 and 8?

Comment: Hello, how are you
I want it to be the same behavior as a mouse button 1

Comment: Exactly the same behavior?  In other words, you need buttons 7 and 8 to be clones of button1 ?

Comment: Or buttons 7 and 8 are for another weapons with different recoil parameters?

Comment: Hello dear, I want it to work in the same way as button 1, and the possibility of controlling the movemousedown for each button alone, is this possible?

Comment: In short, I want button 7 and button 8 also shoot in the game, and control the speed of moving the mouse down.And thank you for your time to help me..

Comment: I am very grateful to you, the script is good, but I have a simple problem, for me I have a button 7 I have a macro that hits intermittent fire and a button 8 Rapid Fire, currently with the script when I press the button 7 and 8 the mouse down moves but for 1 time only and I expected it  When holding down it keeps moving, depending on my macro assignment. Is there a solution to this problem?  and thank you. 

Comment: You can not run two scripts in parallel by pressing their buttons simultaneously.  Either script for button 7 or script for button 8 will work, not both.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.**
Go to the big mouse picture in LGS.
Assign command "Left Click" (or "Primary Click" in GHUB) to both physical buttons 7 and 8.

---

**Step 2.**
Set the script

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
      Sleep(200)
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(0,6)
         Sleep(30)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7 and IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
      Sleep(200)
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(0,6)
         Sleep(30)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8 and IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
      Sleep(200)
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(0,6)
         Sleep(30)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```

Comment: Of course, I applied step 1 and step two. Of course, I am sorry that it was difficult for him to communicate the idea, but I simply have in button 7 and 8, my own macro and I need it in games.. I expected after doing the script correctly the mouse would move down continuously like button 1, but  With the macro in button 7 and 8, the movement down when throwing is not continuous.. and thank you very much for your wonderful effort and patience 

Comment: Why not just add the actual code you are running and video (where we can see the problem) to your question?  See [this issue](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/LGS_extension/issues/4) about how to PM me.

Comment: From video I see that you have not done Step 1.  You must have "Primary Click" on buttons 7 and 8.

Comment: Of course, if I do steps 1, my macro commands will stop, and I need them

Comment: It is another task - to merge "recoil + rapidfire".  It needs another script.

Comment: Aha, I understand, and is it possible to merge the first script with the second?, or is the subject a bit difficult Is there a script that you recommend? ... Thank you very much, and thank you for your patience.. 

Comment: Hi, @MuhanadSaif Just wanted to say that if the original question has been resolved, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1027611) the answer by clicking the check mark. If you are having more/other issues, you can post a new question instead of asking it here.